# How to fetch all Block Storage (ISCSI & Portable storage) for specific virtual guest's runtime id using Softlayer API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In softlayer, block storage can be attached to virtual guest, and that can be seen through softlayer portal's device list for a particular virtual guest. Under block storage, they have ISCSI and portable storages, so i want to fetch all the block storage that are attached for a particular virtual guest using softlayer api.Can anyone please tell me how to achieve it using api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in order to get all attached network storages of a virtual guest you can use the method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getAttachedNetworkStorages

e.g.

```
POST https://$USERNAME:$APIUSER@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$VIRTUALGUESTID/getAttachedNetworkStorages

payload:
{
    "parameters": ["ISCSI"]
}

Note: replace $USERNAME, $APIUSER and $VIRTUALGUESTID
```

In regard the portable storages you can use the method:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes

The method return all portable storages in your account, the catch to get only the attached to your virtual guest is to use a objectFilter e.g.

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes?objectFilter={"portableStorageVolumes": {"blockDevices": {"guest":{"id":{"operation":$VIRTUALGUESTID}}}}}

Note: replace $USERNAME, $APIUSER and $VIRTUALGUESTID
```

Regards